# Divs not controlling layout of links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I have two sets of links on my page (https://breakingtheirchains.com/test.html): navigation links and a simple set of other links down the left side of the page. The navigation links at the top were working fine with this CSS:

```
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .75em;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffe6;
  color: gray;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #ffffe6;
  color: white;
}
```

UNTIL I added a new DIV for the list of links on the page:

```
.links {
  position: relative;
  top: 10;
  left: 20;
  color: #ffffe6;
{
```

Now all the links including the top navigation look the same. You can see how the navigation links should look at https://breakingtheirchains.com/studyguide.html. Please help! Thanks.

I tried changing the CSS for both types of links but nothing changed.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You have a typo (`{` where a `}` would be expected). Please make use of [syntax checking tools](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) before resorting to crowdsourcing help! (Said tool will also pick up at least two more errors that jump out at me when I glance at that code).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is incorrect. You should consider removing the erroneous opening curly brace before the closing brace:

```css
.links {
  position: relative;
  top: 10;
  left: 20;
  color: #ffffe6;
{

}
```

Should be:

```css
.links {
  position: relative;
  top: 10;
  left: 20;
  color: #ffffe6;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.